# Recent Items in Lightning: configure which fields to display

Tags: lightning, recent-item

We just added Recent Items to our Utility Bar in Lightning.  As per the screenshot below, it displays multiple fields, unlike Classic where it just displays the Name.  Where exactly are the fields to display for each object configured?

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it's the same as compact layout.

Comment: That looks right, thanks.  Makes it pretty useless, because highlight fields also uses compact layouts, and there's no reason why highlight fields should show the same info as recent items.

Comment: I'd expect the thinking would be that highlighted fields specified in the Compact Layout would the ones that would be considered important to include with recent records.

Comment: Possibly, but I mainly use - in classic at least - Recent Items to go back to a record I was previously looking at without  having to find it again

Answer (score 0):

In Compact Layout you can select the fields which you want to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

This can be configured from Compact Layout

[image: Compact Layout]

If Existing Compact Layout not having your required field then create new **Compact Layout** and Make it default using **Compact Layout Assignment**.

[image: New Compact Layout]